# Shell Script - How to create variables with specific length?

Tags: shell, variable-length-array

I'm new on shell scripting, and I need a help on this.

How could I create an output file delimited by variable strings? I mean, each variable has an specific length, for example:

```
variable1 (char 10)
variable2 (char 5)
variable3 (char 4)
variable4 (char 7)
variable5 (char 20)
variable6 (char 2)
...
```

The output file would be like this (each number is related to the content of the respective variable):

```
11111     22222333344444445555555             66
```

The content of next variable starts on the next position in the file, i.e., `variable2` starts at 11th position, because the `variable1` ends at 10th position. And the remaining space in the variable would be filled with blank spaces.

Comment: You'll need a while loop that checks `[ ${#VAR} -le 10 ]` and pads with whatever padding until it is true

Comment: @technosaurus Well, that's one way to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf` to print the strings:

```
$ printf "%-10.10s%-5.5s%-4.4s%-7.7s%-20.20s%-2.2s\n" 11111 22222 3333 4444444 5555555 66
11111     22222333344444445555555             66
```

For instance, `%-10.10s` indicates the corresponding argument should be left-justified (-) in a field exactly 10 characters wide.